# for lops and func not printing the code Missing argument for parameter 'in' in call

Tags: swift

I'm trying to print out the names that comes after the search engine clears them so for example I wrote in the searchValue "Mohamed" expecting it to print all Mohameds in the usersSeenStory but it's giving me an error saying **Missing argument for parameter 'in' in call**

```
var usersSeenStory = ("ameerahmed_", "_mohamedalaaa", "afapps", "mohamed_khaled"); // Who seen the story are here.

var searchValue = "mohamed"; // This value is for example. It will be inserted in the search input.


func searchForUser(in arr:[String], for str: String) -> [String] {
    for results in searchValue {
        print(results)
    }

}
searchForUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get only certain Users. To do this, you need to change your code to this:

```
var usersSeenStory = ["ameerahmed_", "_mohamedalaaa", "afapps", "mohamed_khaled"] 

var searchValue = "mohamed"; 


func searchForUser(in arr:[String], for str: String) -> [String] {
    var matchedUsers = [String]()
    for user in arr {
        if let _ = user.range(of: str) {
            matchedUsers.append(user)
        }
    }

    return matchedUsers

}

searchForUser(in: usersSeenStory, for: searchValue)
```

But there is also a shorter version to do this:

```
let filtered = usersSeenStory.filter { $0.range(of: searchValue) != nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to print all the `Mohameds` in your `usersSeenStory` array you just need to add a condition, like that:

```
var usersSeenStory = ("ameerahmed_", "_mohamedalaaa", "afapps", "mohamed_khaled"); // Who seen the story are here.

var searchValue = "mohamed"; // This value is for example. It will be inserted in the search input.


func searchForUser(in arr:[String], for str: String) {
    for results in searchValue {
        if results.contains(str) {
            print(results)
        }
    }

}
searchForUser()
```

or

```
func searchForUser(in arr:[String], for str: String) -> [String] {
    let results = arr.filter{ $0.contains(str) }
    print(results)
    return results
}
```